# What is the meaning of keyword "throws" in Swift?

Tags: swift, syntax, nsdata, nsurl, throws

What is meaning of "throws" keyword here:

[image]

This code take so long to be executed and i think "throws" keyword in the image above related:

```
let url = URL(string:"\(APIs.postsImages)\(postImg)")
let imgData = try? Data.init(contentsOf: url)
self.postImage.image = UIImage.init(data: imgData)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`init() throws`** can return more information about the failure and let the caller decide if they care about it or not. Read a useful post about it [here](https://owensd.io/2015/07/07/init-vs-init-throws/).

> To indicate that a function, method, or initializer can throw an error, you need to write the `throws` keyword in the function’s declaration after its parameters. A function marked with `throws` is called a **throwing function**. If the function specifies a return type, you write the throws keyword before the return arrow.

```
func thisFunctionCanThrowErrors() throws -> String
```

or in real code it might look like this:

```
enum PossibleErrors: Error {
    case wrongUsername
    case wrongPassword
}

func loggingIn(name: String, pass: String) throws -> String {

    if name.isEmpty { 
        throw PossibleErrors.wrongUsername 
    }
    if pass.isEmpty { 
        throw PossibleErrors.wrongPassword 
    }
    return "Fine"
}
```

The `throwing functions` like this must be called using one of the following try operators:

- **try**
- **try?**
- **try!**

Using `init() throws` you can break the execution of a class initialiser without the need of populating all stored properties:

```
class TestClass {

    let textFile: String

    init() throws {
        do {
            textFile = try String(contentsOfFile: "/Users/swift/text.txt", 
                                        encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        catch let error as NSError {
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

And in a structure you can even avoid the `do/catch` block:

```
struct TestStruct {

    var textFile: String

    init() throws {
        textFile = try String(contentsOfFile: "/Users/swift/text.txt", 
                                    encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
}
```

Comment: i used guard and steal take a long time    "guard let imgData = try? Data.init(contentsOf: url) else { return }"

Comment: It's OK as well. Remember, if you use "guard" with "try?" (not just "try") – the possible error message will be ignored.

Comment: but why its take a while before go to the next line and how to avoid that?

Comment: Sorry, avoid what?

Comment: when code execute the line of "guard let imgData = try? Data.init(contentsOf: url) else { return }" take a little time more than any other line why ?? and can i do any thing to make it faster ??

Comment: Because If you use "guard filePath" value – it is available to scope that is "guard" called in. And because "try?" is optional...

Answer (score 4):

The `throws` keyword indicates that a function may throw an error. I.e., it is a **throwing function**. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) for additional details.